# MongoDb - find what is my current read and write concern for the cluster

Tags: mongodb

I am working with MongoDb version 4.2.

I searched the documentation to find how to get my cluster read and write concern defaults, but couldn't.

Is there no shell command that shows this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [getDefaultRWConcern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getDefaultRWConcern/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.getDefaultRWConcern) administrative command retrieves the global default read or write concern settings.

Comment: Hi, Looks like this command available only since 4.4, while I am working on 4.2. Any equivilent for this version?

Comment: Check out https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/mongodb-defaults/#default-mongodb-read-concerns-write-concerns